# node.js script works off command line but not from browser?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I launched and amazon ec2 instance running ubuntu 12.04

I then followed the instructions to install node.js from here http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs

```
sudo apt-get install g++ curl libssl-dev apache2-utils
sudo apt-get install git-core

git clone git://github.com/ry/node.git
cd node
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I then used the example code to make `hello.js`

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello Node.js\n');
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

I then ran `hello.js`

```
/var/www$ node hello.js
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/
```

However, when I try to access this from the url, with `http://ec2-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8124/` I get an error page from my browser.

Any advice on how to get it to show up in the browser?

**EDIT**
I'm still encountering this problem after changing the above line of code

```
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
```

to this

```
}).listen(8124);
```

Answer (score 2):

127.0.0.1 is the loopback address.  Only the host can access it.  If you want to listen on any available IP, just don't specify that parameter.  Otherwise, specify the real IP you want to listen on.

Comment: I changed this line of code `}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");` to this `}).listen(8124);` but it's still not loading.  I also added the tcp port 8124 to the security group but I'm still facing the same problem.

Comment: user784637, SSH into your box, and run `telnet 127.0.0.1 8124`.  Does the connection work?  (You won't get output unless you make a valid request, but I'm more interested in whether or not a connection is working.)  Then, do the same test from your desk.

Comment: Arg... I get the following output `/var/www# telnet 127.0.0.1 8124
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused` Any idea on why I can't establish a connection?  Do I need to forward traffic from 8124 to a port <= 1024 (I think amazon has a rule that doesn't allow traffic from ports >1024)

Comment: Have you tried a different port?  Such as port 80?  Either the server isn't listening, or there is some sort of firewall blocking you.

Comment: If I m not wrong in AWS EC2 we need to add IP's which can access certain port in security groups, have you done that. I dont think port 8124 is open for all.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue, Uninstalling skype worked for me, You can also search for some setting which force skype to move to some other port.